# Photoshop: pressing CTRL to see related position of the layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, guides

I am using PS CC 2015 on my windows 10 machine. When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> some guidelines will appear indicating the distance between the selected layer and the layer which the mouse is pointing to, as seen in the picture below.

First, is there a name for this "feature"? Secondly, on My mac I am using the same version PS CC, but I tried pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> but none of them will bring up the guidelines. So does PS CC on Mac not provide this feature?

[image]

Comment: Those are called Smart Guides and it could be activated by `Choose View > Show > Smart Guides.`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have **Smart Guides** turned on: "View > Show > Smart Guides".

Have your mouse over the canvas and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> for Windows or <kbd>Command</kbd> for Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a feature of the very latest PS. I upgrade it and it works.

Answer (score -1):

These are "Smart Guides". Go on View on the top tool bar. You will see an option called "show" and click on "Smart Guides". The guides will appear.

[image]
[image]

Comment: these are not regular guides, check the other answer.

Comment: @Luciano Yes, my mistake. I have updated it .

Comment: still, your answer just repeats a previous one posted more than 6 months ago. Please check other answers before posting your own. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!